# Volley error bad url null and BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 405

Tags: android, get, android-volley

Hi I am trying to get data from a web API using get method of volley. But I keep getting these errors.

```
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, uri, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {


            Log.i("response", response);

       }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

            Log.i("error", error.toString());
        }
    });



  AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(stringRequest);
```

Errors:

```
pp E/Volley: [132] NetworkDispatcher.run: Unhandled exception java.lang.RuntimeException: Bad URL null
                                                                           java.lang.RuntimeException: Bad URL null

p E/Volley: [131] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 405
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: what is uri you are passing?

Comment: http://horoscope-api.herokuapp.com/horoscope/today/pisces this one

Comment: http://horoscope-api.herokuapp.com/horoscope/today/pisces

have you added http:// before url?

Comment: yes i have added http

Answer (score 0):

You are getting "Unexpected response code 405", so it has something to do with the server response.

"The 405 Method Not Allowed is an HTTP response status code indicating that the specified request HTTP method was received and recognized by the server, but the server has rejected that particular method for the requested resource."

Answer (score 0):

Problem is in client side. The issue is that the request is set to POST by default. Use one of below 2 methods. Both work fine for me.

```
public void getJsonData(){
        JsonObjectRequest jsonReq = new JsonObjectRequest
                (Request.Method.GET, URL_FEED, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        Log.d("response", response);
                    }
                },
                        new Response.ErrorListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                                Log.d("Server", "onErrorResponse");
                            }
                        });
        NetworkController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonReq);}
```

2nd Method

```
public void getJsonData() {
                    final String URL = "URL";
                    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, URL,
                            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onResponse(String response) {
                                    Log.i("response", response);
                                }
                            },
                            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                                    Log.i("error", error.toString());
                                }
                            }) {};
                    final RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
                    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
                    requestQueue.addRequestFinishedListener(new RequestQueue.RequestFinishedListener<Object>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onRequestFinished(Request<Object> request) {
                            requestQueue.getCache().clear();
                        }
                    });
                }
```